# Volkswagen Jetta 2006 front right door window stopped working

Tags: vw, power-windows, door, jetta

Recently my front passenger door window stopped working. Is there anything I can try at home to fix it?

Comment: Is it an electric or crank powered window? Did the window go off track (stuck in the frame sideways)? If powered, does the switch power the other three windows in the car? How was it that it stopped working? Was it all of a sudden or was it getting really slow and then stopped moving? As it's written, this question is *way too vague* to even start to answer.

Comment: It is electric and it is not off track it went all the way down like always and just stopped working all of a sudden. The other windows still do work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, when you hit the switch, you hear nothing (no binding noises from the motor), then it probably is your motor at fault. You'll need to open the inside door panel and check the leads for power. If you get power through the leads (leads being the plug at the window motor), then it's probably your motor at fault. You can check your motor by applying power directly to it.

Comment: do you think maybe it is the motor? because not even the switch from the drivers side works for that window.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question and thought you were talking about the DS window. I will update my answer.